# Using the requests to login to a website(Mediawiki) with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, mediawiki

I want to use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) library in Python3 to login to a [Mediawiki](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki) Website.

I already looked for similar topics but the solution I ended with does not work.

The login formular I want to use looks like this:

```
<form name="userlogin" class="mw-ui-vform" method="post" action="/index.php?title=Spezial:Anmelden&amp;action=submitlogin&amp;type=login&amp;returnto=Hauptseite">
    <section class="mw-form-header"></section>

    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field">
        <label for='wpName1'> Benutzername </label>
        <input class="loginText mw-ui-input" id="wpName1" tabindex="1" autofocus="" placeholder="Gib deinen Benutzernamen ein" name="wpName"/>
    </div>

    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field">
        <label for='wpPassword1'> Passwort </label>
        <input class="loginPassword mw-ui-input" id="wpPassword1" tabindex="2" placeholder="Gib dein Passwort ein" type="password" name="wpPassword" />
    </div>

    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field">
        <div class="mw-ui-checkbox">
            <input name="wpRemember" type="checkbox" value="1" id="wpRemember" tabindex="4">
            <label for="wpRemember"> Angemeldet bleiben</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field">
        <input id="wpLoginAttempt" name="wpLoginAttempt" tabindex="6" type="submit" value="Anmelden" class="mw-ui-button mw-ui-constructive" />
    </div>

    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field mw-form-related-link-container" id="mw-userlogin-help">
        <a href="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Logging_in">Hilfe beim Anmelden</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mw-ui-vform-field mw-form-related-link-container">
        <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Passwort_neu_vergeben" title="Spezial:Passwort neu vergeben">Passwort vergessen?</a>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="9a57c2f503220304d0cc80633bad12d1" name="wpLoginToken" />
</form>
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import requests
import re
a=('user','pass')

postloginurl='https://example.com/index.php?title=Spezial:Anmelden&amp;action=submitlogin&amp;type=login&amp;returnto=Hauptseite'
requesturl='https://example.com/index.php/Hauptseite'   


with requests.Session() as session:
  session.auth=a

  #finding the logintoken for the formular
  get = session.get(postloginurl)
  m=re.search('value="(?P<logintoken>.*)" name="wpLoginToken"',get.text)
  logintoken=m.group('logintoken')

  #fill out the login formular
  name=input('name:')
  password=input('password:')
  payload={'action': 'login', 'wpName':name, 'wpPassword':password, 'wpRemember':'1' , 'wpLoginAttempt':'Anmelden', 'wpLoginToken':logintoken, 'submit':'submit'}
  post = session.post(postloginurl, data=payload)

  #test if I'm logged in
  r = session.get(requesturl)
  print(r.text)
  #here it says: ""wgUserName":null" in the head, so I'm not logged in
```

The site also uses an authentification so I need the auth part.
I also tried to manage the logintoken, which changes everytime I start a new session.

Do you guys have an idea what could be wrong or what I could test to find my mistake?

Comment: What do you want to do? Why can't you use the MediaWiki API?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `headers` into login request. There is no need to add 'user' and 'pass' into `session.auth`.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

login_page_url = 'https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=MediaWiki'
login_url = 'https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=MediaWiki'

# Create Session.
session = requests.session()

# Get HTML of Login page.
response = session.get(login_page_url)

# Extract token from HTML using BeautifulSoup.
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
wpLoginToken = soup.find('input', {'name': 'wpLoginToken'}).get('value')

payload = {
    "wpName":"YOUR_USERNAME",
    "wpPassword":"YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "wpRemember":"1", "authAction":"login",
    "wpLoginToken":wpLoginToken}

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.mediawiki.org','Origin': 'https://www.mediawiki.org', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=MediaWiki',
}

# Login request.
response = session.post(login_url, data=payload,)
print(response.status_code, response.text)
```

and can find your username in `response.text` ("wgUserName":"YOUR_USERNAME")